# How can I perform a replacement a specified number of times per line?

Tags: substitute

Using `vim`, I know that I can replace all occurrences of a string across multiple lines by specifying a *count* or a *range*, as documented in `:h subst`.

I have a markdown table which contains C function prototypes, as well as English prose. I would like to replace, for example, the word 'float', but only the first three occurrences.

If I were writing a program to do this, many languages have a `.replace` method on strings that will accept a `howmany` parameter that limits the number of times the replacement is made.

Can I do something like that with `vim`? Is there any way to say, for example, "replace `float` with `long double` at most 3 times"?

Comment: This was asked for several years back on the vim-use mailinglist and one user came up with this solution: https://groups.google.com/g/vim_use/c/EDAQl0g09XY/m/Er6Q7E1o6noJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a straight programmatic approach, we can simply implement this as a `for` loop:

```
:for x in range(3) | :%s/float/long double/ | endfor
```

**Update:** @PeterRincker offers this user command that you can wrap around the above for easy invocation:

```
command! -count=1 -nargs=+ -complete=command Times for _ in range(<count>) | execute '<args>' | endfor.
```

Then for the above example we'd just need...

```
:3Times %s/float/long double/
```

Comment: In case this is a common thing: `command! -count=1 -nargs=+ -complete=command Times for _ in range(<count>) | execute '<args>' | endfor`. Now they can do `:3Times s/foo/bar/`

Comment: Good stuff @PeterRincker. I added it to my answer. Cheers.

Comment: This is nicely pragmatic. And the extra `Times` command is just whipped cream on top of the cake. If I could give another +1 I would.

Comment: @aghast LOL. I'm glad you're enjoying the dessert we served. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Because I love macros, here's a simple macro based-solution:

1. [Record a macro](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#complex-repeat) to replace one instance of float on the current line:

   ```
    qq:s/float/long double<CR>q
                          ^^^^
                          Press Return here
   ```
2. (If necessary) Undo the change you just made by hitting <kbd>u</kbd>
3. [Play the macro](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%40) three times [on each line in your file](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Anormal-range):

   ```
    :%norm! 3@q
   ```

Comment: I like this approach. It fits well with "normal" use and seems likely to be something one could stumble upon while floundering around looking for a better way. I had never thought of `:%norm` as a valid option before now, which means I learned something from this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can also prepare the repeated text with

```
:let list = repeat(['long double'], 3)
```

and then replace with:

```
:s/float/\=empty(l) ? submatch(0) : remove(list,0)/g
```

Alas, I'm not inspired at this time for solving the resetting of the list for each new line with a `:%s/...`. Well we could work with `repeat([repeat(['long double'], 3)], line('$'))` and then remove from `list[line('.')]`. It's a bit overkill, but quite possibly much more faster than `:for` based solutions with vimscript < 9.

Note: It can certainly be built into a command like (in other similar Q/A I've provided multiple examples of such encapsulation of `:substitute` ([SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809571/how-do-i-substitute-from-a-list-of-strings-in-vim), ...)

```
:SubstituteFirst/3/float/long double
```

Comment: Perhaps use a `:global` to reset it? `:g/float/ let list = repeat(['long double'], 3) | s//\=empty(l) ? submatch(0) : remove(list,0)/g`

Comment: In a 5900 line text file a `for` loop substitution with a pattern that has 20K matches completes with no discernible delay on the two systems I tried it on.